# How to make grid item responsive to viewport?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am creating a website that has a header, a sidebar on the left, a main content at the center, where information will be displayed, a right side-bar, and a footer that will contain an image or something. The header and footer were left out of the grid template.

For this question I am focusing only on the following classes: `.sidebar(left-sidebar aka a table of content or index),` `.contenido-carrera(information displayed),` and `.publicidad(right-sidebar)`

All the sections were defined by using this piece of CSS

```css
.carrera-grid {
    margin: 120px 12px;
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: 230px fit-content(80ch) 170px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

You can tell the content in the center is by far the largest. First sidebar will contain a list of elements like "Table of contents" on Wikipedia, and the one with 170px will be kept for publicity.

```
.sidebar {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}

.publicidad {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: center;
    left: 10px;
    top: 50px;
    flex-flow: column;
}

.publicidad > div {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 6px;
}
```

I tried to set `display:flex` just on the centered element, `.contenido-carrera` but this makes a undesired/unwanted layout/design, makes all items to lose their width and space between them while not using the fixed space that was intended on the grid.

```css
.contenido-carrera {
    text-align: justify;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 90px;
}
```

https://streamable.com/b6itn
As you can see, the item on the centered element is affected by an overflow within itself. So how can I make this as responsive as possible? Thought of using media-queries but am currently running bootstrap on this page, so I wouldn't like to get in the way of that.

Like previously mentioned the header and footer were left out of the grid-template.

```html
      <main class="carrera-grid">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <ol>
          <label>Tabla de Contenidos</label>
          <li>¿Qué es la Mercadotecnia?</li>
          <li>Objetivos de la Mercadotecnia</li>
          <li>Tipos de Mercadotecnia</li>
          <li>Importancia de la Mercadotecnia</li>
          <li>Para qué nos Sirve la Mercadotecnia</li>
          <ul> <!-- Inicio de PRIMERA subdivision de lista-->
            <li>Crear una imagen corporativa</li>
          <li>Atraer clientes</li>
          <li>Mejora la estrategia de publicidad</li>
          <li>Tomar decisiones</li>
        </li>
      </ul> <!-- Fin de PRIMERA subdivision de lista-->
        <li>Ejemplos de Mercadotecnia</li>
        <ol> <!-- Inicio de SEGUNDA subdivision de lista-->
          <li>Uber</li>
          <li>Whirlpool</li>
          <li>Andes Bar 45</li>
          <li>Netflix</li>
          <li>Walmart</li>
        </ol> <!-- Fin de SEGUNDA subdivision de lista-->
        <li>Cuáles son los elementos de un Plan de Mercadotecnia o Plan de Marketing</li>
        <ol> <!-- Inicio de TERCERA subdivision de lista-->
          <li>Investigación</li>
          <li>Producto</li>
          <li>Análisis de la competencia</li>
          <li>Presupuesto</li>
          <li>Precio, posicionamiento y marca</li>
          <li>Traza objetivos reales</li>
          <li>Monitorea y analiza los resultados</li>
          </ol> <!-- fIN de TERCERA subdivision de lista-->
          <li>Cómo definir una estrategia de Marketing Online</li>
          <li>Conclusión</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      <div class="contenido-carrera">
        <h1>¿Qué es la Mercadotecnia?</h1>
        <p style="font-weight: bold;">La mercadotecnia es un conjunto actividades que se realizan para identificar las necesidades de un
          público determinado con el objeto de brindarle productos o servicios para satisfacerlos de la forma más adecuada.</p>
          <p>La mercadotecnia se encarga del proceso de planificación de las actividades de la empresa en relación con: el precio, la promoción,
            distribución y venta de bienes y servicios que ofrece.</p>
            <p><strong>Ayuda a definir el producto o servicio de acuerdo con las preferencias de los consumidores con el fin de acelerar el <a href="#">proceso de compras.</a></strong>
              De esta manera se podrá crear un intercambio entre las empresas y consumidores que satisfaga los objetivos de ambas partes.<br>
              <br><a href="#">Philip Kotler</a>, el gurú del marketing, dice que la mercadotecnia​ es:

              <div class="frase">
                <p>“El proceso social y administrativo por el cual los grupos e individuos<br>
                  satisfacen sus necesidades al crear e intercambiar bienes
                  y servicios”</p>
              </div><br>
              Según la <a href="#">Asociación Americana de Marketing</a> (AMA, por sus siglas en inglés)<br>
              <br>

              <div class="frase-lg">
                  <p>“la actividad, el conjunto de instituciones y los procesos para crear,
                    comunicar, entregar e intercambiar ofertas que tienen valor para los
                    clientes, clientes, socios y la sociedad en general.”
                    </p>
                </div><br>
                Por su parte, William J. Stanton dice que la mercadotecnia se refiere:<br>

                <br><div class="frase">
                    <p>“al desarrollo de las actividades del negocio que dirigen el flujo de
                      mercancías y servicios del productor hacia el consumidor o usuario.”</p>
                  </div><br>
                  Finalmente, Martin L. Bed conceptualiza la mercadotecnia como aquellas “actividades integradas de una empresa, dirigidas hacia la satisfacción de las necesidades
                  de los clientes con un margen de utilidad.”
                  <br>En resumen, la mercadotecnia implica la incorporación de una serie de técnicas, estrategias y prácticas cuyo objetivo principal es agregar valor a las diferentes marcas o productos a fin de satisfacer las necesidades de los consumidores.
            </p>
      </div>
      <div class="publicidad">
        <div class="publicidad-1">Publicidad</div>
        <div class="publicidad-2">Publicidad</div>
      </div>

    </main>
```

Comment: Either, you use media queries or you try this: https://css-tricks.com/look-ma-no-media-queries-responsive-layouts-using-css-grid/

Comment: You're welcome. Please share, if it helped or not! You can even answer your own question (and gain points for it).